# iPad - Popover frame color

Tags: objective-c, ipad, ios, uisplitviewcontroller

So I have a split view application I am working on and have encountered a strange UI bug.  Here goes my best attempt to explain it.  If I load the app in landscape mode, the top navigation bar of the root controller is the proper color.  I am doing this in rootView's ViewWillAppear method:

```
self.rvBar.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:59.0/255
                               green:115.0/255
                    blue:185.0/255
                       alpha:1];
```

Now when I rotate the device, and display the view via a popover, the popover is black.  Do you know how to change the color of the popover to the same blue?  I have tried doing this in the `willHide/ShowViewController` methods in the split view controller delegate, but nothing seems to work.

Now part two, when I rotate back to landscape, the line above is called again, but instead of displaying the blue bar, it's now grey!  Has anyone seen a splitview behave like this before, and if so, what needs to be done to fix it??  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried doing it in the viewDidAppear method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have discovered the solution to this problem if anyone is still wondering.

After doing some digging, I discovered that there is an Apple bug that disables the modification of the UIToolBar tintColor property, and it gets stuck in whatever state it's in.  I had to send a message to the tintColor property in order to tell it that it is modifiable.

```
extern id objc_msgSend (id, SEL, BOOL);
objc_msgSend([(UINavigationController *)aViewController navigationBar], @selector(_setDisableCustomTint:), NO);
/* Set the tintColor again */
[(UINavigationController *)aViewController navigationBar].tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:59.0/255
                                                                                      green:115.0/255
                                                                                       blue:185.0/255
                                                                                      alpha:1];
```

Obviously this won't be acceptable if you plan on submitting your application to the Apple store, but for my purposes this did the trick.  Hope this helps some of you guys out there...

Comment: It is a solution, but as you said it is not suitable for appStore - thus irrelevante.

Comment: Whatever you say tex.  For my purposes, we had an app that wasn't used by the public, so therefore it was relevant.  For anyone that needed a solution for that reason.

Comment: fine, I removed the down arrow ;)

Answer (score 2):

I tried this on a basic SplitViewController project (in the RootViewController) :

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:59.0/255
                                                                        green:115.0/255
                                                                         blue:185.0/255
                                                                        alpha:1];
}
```

and it works fine. When you say that the popover remains black you mean that the title background is black ? (for me it's blue and the popover borders are black).

Maybe the problem comes from elsewhere, how do you set your rvBar property ?

Comment: Yeah, the title background stays black.  I know you can't change the popover frame color, but it doesn't make sense why it would change the navigation bar to grey once you rotate it back.  I am setting the rvBar property from IB.  It's weird because it works when the view loads, but as soon as the popover displays and it rotates back, it turns grey...

Comment: Have you tried to set the navbar tint color directly in IB rather than programmatically. I can't manage to reproduce the bug.

Comment: The way the splitview controller is set up, you can't change it for some reason.  There is no option to do so.  Very irritating...

Comment: Don't you have your SplitViewController in a XIB file ? When you start a project with a SplitViewController you get the following configuration: [default config screenshot](http://localhostr.com/files/cDnXMwJ/splitview.png)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change the `Popover`'s `tintColor`, the property does not exist.

For more info on Popover's, check out the [`UIPopoverController Class Reference`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPopoverController_class/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: Alright, I figured that was the case there.  But that still doesn't explain why it is changing the bar to grey once the button is invalidated and the view reappears in the left pane...

Answer (score 0):

you can also change the navigation bar (of the Rootviewcontroller) via the Interface Builder; just have to select the navigation bar from the list on the left and change the tint property by selecting from rgb matrix or any other means you chose.