# How can I change the popover color frame?

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller, uipopovercontroller

I would change the popover color in an ipad splitview application.

So I would change the default blue color:

[image]

in a red color for example. How can I do?

Answer (score 1):

Sadly you cannot achieve that as per documentation.

Stated here: [iPad - Popover frame color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5225353/ipad-popover-frame-color/5227594#5227594)

All you could do it to set the color for the landscape mode as follows:

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
```